# Problem with installing NuGet packages

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to install NuGet packages like Unity or EntityFramework, but after downloading Nuget cannot install those and returns this error message:

```
Your machine group policy or user group policy disables execution of PowerShell script.
Adjust your group policy settings to allow execution of PowerShell scripts
```

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What version of NuGet are you using? Try upgrading to the latest version. It sounds like this issue: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/834

Comment: My NuGet version is 1.3.20419.9007 and I've changed PowerShell ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted. But my problem isn't solved yet!

Comment: Note: I've tested this issue with Administrator account and everything is find but I have this problem inside my own account (Sadegh) However this account also is under Admonistrators!

Comment: According to the workitem, the issue (if it indeed is the issue I linked to) is resolved in 1.4. Try 1.4 and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently old version of NuGet aka not > 1.4 do not sign powershell scripts and thus you need to run the following from a powershell command line:

```
set-executionpolicy Unrestricted
```

in 1.4 we are going to sign the scripts so you shouldn't have this problem. Although 1.4 has not shipped yet, but very very soon :)

The above fix might fail if your administrator has locked down powershell scripts in that case you can either ask them to do this for you or wait till NuGet 1.4 is released.

Comment: I'm Administrator! Now how can I Unlock PowerShell to be able to execute PS scripts?

Comment: Just open the Powershell 2 command window should be a link in your start menu and type the command above (the Set-Execution blah blah one)

Comment: 1.4 or latest is available to build from source: http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: @Matt Please read comment#2 of my question. I have done before.

Comment: Its seems We should make changes into Group Policy or somewhere?

Comment: @PHeiberg why not just grab it from our public build server? Ci.NuGet.Org?

Comment: @Sadegh sorry I didnt see that. When you run get-executionpolicy what is returned? Are you running Powershell 2.0?

Comment: Yes I'm running PowerShell 2.0 and result of Get-ExecutionPolicy is **Unrestricted**.